# CSS divs float in eachother

Tags: html, css

I want to fix my code but I seem to fail. I hope that anyone can help me since I want to fix it!

I want the logo top right, and the menu top left. Also when you scroll it may not move just like it is now!

```css
body {
  background: url(background.jpg);
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
}
.box {
  border-style: solid;
  margin-bottom: 200px
}
#logo img{
  width:140px;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#menu {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: inset;
  border-color: #DCA970;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 7px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
} 
li  {
  margin: 10px;
}
.hello {
  margin-top: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <title>Monster Dung</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="logo.png">
        <div id="menu">
          <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Shop</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>Forum</li>
          </ul> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p> Hey there<p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want everything to scroll when you scroll be page?  If so, get rid of position:fixed and use position:absolute instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you wanna fixed header like this?

```css
body {
  background: url(background.jpg);
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
}
.box {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#logo img{
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  width:140px;
  height: auto;
}
#menu {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: inset;
  border-color: #DCA970;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 7px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
} 
li  {
  margin: 10px;
}
.hello {
  margin-top: 1000px;
}
.content {
  height: 1000px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <title>Monster Dung</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="logo.png">
        <div id="menu">
          <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Shop</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>Forum</li>
          </ul> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p> Hey there<p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want.I wrote a code for you.I think this will help to you.just replace your image .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>



  
<style type="text/css">
 body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
 }
 div.main{
  position: fixed;
 }

 div.navigation{
  border:1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px black;
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
  
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
 
 div.navigation ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -25px;
 }
 div.navigation ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;

 }

 div.logoimage{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px orange;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;



 }

 div.logoimage img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

 }

</style>


<body>

 <div class="main">
    <div class="navigation">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Forum</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>  
    <div class="logoimage">
     <img src="yourlogo.png"/>
    </div>
 </div>
  

</body>
</html>
```